# In an attempt to map US regions in R, I am getting a persistent error. Can someone identify what I've done wrong?

Tags: r

I am getting the following error in my attempt to map the regions of the United States in R studio.

Error in data.frame(region = c("Northeast", "Ohiovalley", "RockiesPlains",  :
arguments imply differing number of rows: 9, 8

The code is below:

```
# Load required libraries
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)
library(maps)

# Load US map data
us_map <- st_as_sf(map("state", plot = FALSE, fill = TRUE))

# Create a data frame with 8 regions and their corresponding states
regions_data <- data.frame(
  region = c("Northeast", "Ohiovalley", "RockiesPlains", "South", "Northwest", "Southwest", "West", "Southeat", "UpperMidwest" ),
  states = list(
                c("DE", "ME", "MD", "MA", "NJ", "CT", "NY", "PA"),
                c("IL", "IN", "KY", "MO", "OH", "TN", "WV", "NA"),
                c("MT", "NE", "ND", "SD", "WY", "NA", "NA", "NA"),
                c("AR", "KS", "LA", "MS", "OK", "TX", "NA", "NA"),
                c("WA", "OR", "ID", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA"),
                c("AZ", "CO", "NM", "UT", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA"),
                c("CA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA"),
                c("AL", "GA", "FL", "NC", "SC", "VA", "NA", "NA"),
                c("IA", "MN", "WI", "MI", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA"))
)

# Ensure that all state codes are in uppercase
regions_data$states <- lapply(regions_data$states, function(x) ifelse(!is.na(x), toupper(x), NA))

# Flatten the list of states to create a mapping data frame
mapping_df <- regions_data %>%
  select(region) %>%
  unnest(states)

# Merge region data with US map data
us_map_regions <- left_join(us_map, mapping_df, by = c("ID" = "states"))

# Plot the map
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = us_map_regions, aes(fill = region)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = rainbow(length(unique(regions_data$region))), name = "Region") +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(title = "US Regions Map (8 Regions)", subtitle = "Customized Regions") +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

I've tried troubleshooting, moving some commas and removing or adding them without success.  I admit to being basically a noob coder so I may have missed something blazingly obvious.

Comment: You're defining 9 regions instead of 8 when creating the `regions_data` dataframe, so it gives the error you mention.

Comment: But there are nine regions listed? Do I need to change something in the code so it realizes that?

Comment: For a custom object to store region/state data, I would consider a list instead of a data.frame (and not requiring "NA" to be rectangular). When you join your data, you'll want to notice that the `us_map` data includes state names and not abbreviations...

Comment: So I need to type out the state names rather than the abbreviations?

Comment: I'm afraid I will need an example. I'm not a good coder at all. I'm trying to get up to speed but I'm nowhere close. I appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a complete example.

You can put your selected states into a list `regions_data` as below. Notice that each region can then have a varying number of states, and you don't need to pad with missing `NA`.

Following your code, you can use this list to create a data.frame to join with map data, based on lower case state names. Using available `state.abb` and `state.name` this is relative easy to do.

Let me know if this helps and is what you had in mind. Note that a few states are not included in the list and are missing (e.g., Nevada, Vermont, New Hampshire...).

```
# Load required libraries
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)
library(maps)
library(tidyverse)

# Load US map data
us_map <- st_as_sf(maps::map("state", plot = FALSE, fill = TRUE))

regions_data <- list(
  Northeast = c("DE", "ME", "MD", "MA", "NJ", "CT", "NY", "PA"),
  OhioValley =  c("IL", "IN", "KY", "MO", "OH", "TN", "WV"),
  RockiesPlains = c("MT", "NE", "ND", "SD", "WY"),
  South = c("AR", "KS", "LA", "MS", "OK", "TX"),
  Northwest = c("WA", "OR", "ID"),
  Southwest = c("AZ", "CO", "NM", "UT"),
  West = "CA",
  Southeast = c("AL", "GA", "FL", "NC", "SC", "VA"),
  UpperMidwest =  c("IA", "MN", "WI", "MI")
)

mapping_df <- enframe(regions_data, name = "region", value = "state") %>%
  unnest(state) %>%
  left_join(data.frame(state.abb, state.name), by = c("state" = "state.abb")) %>%
  mutate(state.name = tolower(state.name))

us_map_regions <- left_join(us_map, mapping_df, by = c("ID" = "state.name"))

# Plot the map
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = us_map_regions, aes(fill = region)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = rainbow(n_distinct(regions_data)), name = "Region") +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(title = "US Regions Map (8 Regions)", subtitle = "Customized Regions") +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

**Map**

[image: map with colored regions]

Comment: Thank you! I shall try that! 

Edit: It worked! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

The data frame has to be created with `cbind`, otherwise `data.frame` assumes the list entries *states* as column, which are only 8 rows long.

```
data.frame(cbind(
  region = c("Northeast", "Ohiovalley", "RockiesPlains", "South", 
             "Northwest", "Southwest", "West", "Southeat", "UpperMidwest" ),
  states = list(
                c("DE", "ME", "MD", "MA", "NJ", "CT", "NY", "PA"),
                c("IL", "IN", "KY", "MO", "OH", "TN", "WV", "NA"),
                c("MT", "NE", "ND", "SD", "WY", "NA", "NA", "NA"),
                c("AR", "KS", "LA", "MS", "OK", "TX", "NA", "NA"),
                c("WA", "OR", "ID", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA"),
                c("AZ", "CO", "NM", "UT", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA"),
                c("CA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA"),
                c("AL", "GA", "FL", "NC", "SC", "VA", "NA", "NA"),
                c("IA", "MN", "WI", "MI", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA"))
))
         region                         states
1     Northeast DE, ME, MD, MA, NJ, CT, NY, PA
2    Ohiovalley IL, IN, KY, MO, OH, TN, WV, NA
3 RockiesPlains MT, NE, ND, SD, WY, NA, NA, NA
4         South AR, KS, LA, MS, OK, TX, NA, NA
5     Northwest WA, OR, ID, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
6     Southwest AZ, CO, NM, UT, NA, NA, NA, NA
7          West CA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
8      Southeat AL, GA, FL, NC, SC, VA, NA, NA
9  UpperMidwest IA, MN, WI, MI, NA, NA, NA, NA
```

Comment: So do I need to move the cbind in front of the data.frame rather than have it inside?

Comment: `cbind` creates a matrix, `data.frame` creates the desired class *data.frame*. It works like shown in the answer, `data.frame(cbind(...))`.

Comment: Oh I see. Sorry first time using the site, didn't realize that wasn't my code in your answer. Thanks. I'll try that

Edit: That throws another error:
Error: unexpected symbol in "region                         states"

Comment: I focussed on solving the error stated in the question. What I see further on is that you `select(region)` and then work on `states` which is impossible. I don't know where your new error occurs.